# Why do www site and naked site have much of the same data in Webmaster Tools?

Tags: google-search-console

My naked domain has always had a 301 redirect to the www domain. SERPs always display the www version.

I added the www domain to Webmasters tools a while back. I recently added the naked domain as a site and set the preferred domain to www.

I expected there to be practically no data for the naked domain site. However, I see the exact same information for

- Top queries
- Top pages
- Number of pages indexed

Why am I seeing this data for the naked domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The naked domain is a rollup of all the subdomains.

I have a site that is available in several languages with subdomains such as `de.` and `es.`.   The English site is available on the naked domain.   I can't get just data for the English site separated out in Google Webmaster Tools.